# How to perform bincount on an array of strings?

Tags: python, arrays, string, pandas, numpy

I have NumPy array containing string values.

For instance: ["bus", "bar", "bar", "café" .....]

What is the best way of counting the number of occurrences of each element in my array. My current solution is:

```
# my_list contains my data.
bincount = []
for name in set(my_list.tolist()):
    count = sum([1 for elt in my_list if elt == name])
    bincount.append(count)
```

I have tried bincount but it does not work with this type of data.

Do you know a better solution?

Comment: Use `pd.factorize` and _then_ use `np.bincount`.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

#### `np.unique`

```
l = ['bus', 'bar', 'bar', 'café', 'bus', 'bar', 'café']
a, b = np.unique(l, return_counts=True)

a
# array(['bar', 'bus', 'café'], dtype='<U4')

b
# array([3, 2, 2])
```

---

#### `pd.value_counts`

```
pd.value_counts(l)

bar     3
bus     2
café    2
dtype: int64

# <=0.23
pd.value_counts(l).values
# 0.24+
pd.value_counts(l).to_numpy()
# array([3, 2, 2])
```

Make sure pandas is imported (`import pandas as pd`).

---

#### `pd.factorize`

```
np.bincount(pd.factorize(l)[0])
# array([2, 3, 2])
```

This converts the string to numeric categories (or factors, if you prefer), and counts them.

---

#### `pd.get_dummies`

```
pd.get_dummies(l).sum()

bar     3
bus     2
café    2
dtype: int64
```

Slightly roundabout, but interesting nevertheless.

Comment: the best answer is .value_counts() FYI

Comment: @Jeff Updated, thank you, I had no clue it was a module level function.

Comment: You can also use `return_counts` with `np.unique` and thus avoid `bincount` altogether.

Comment: @Divakar Wow! I did not even know that was possible. Thanks for your valuable suggestion - I've edited.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use dictionary in python.

```
result_dict = {}
l = ['bus', 'bar', 'bar', 'café', 'bus', 'bar', 'café']
for ele in l:
    result_dict[ele] = 1 if ele not in result_dict else result_dict[ele] + 1
```

Then print the result:

```
for key in result_dict:
    print key, result_dict[key]
```

reuslt:

```
bus 2
bar 3
café 2
```